# Improving checkout, how do I increase convesion

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout

we are using Queldorei Shopper theme @ shirtsofholland.com. We have many clients asking about our checkout: unclear, many steps etc ...

I was wondering what I can do, because we urgently need to increase conversion. I am thinking across 2 lines and my question is:

**a. install a onepagecheckout extension**

- But which one is fully compatible with my theme *Queldorei shopper*? we dont want conflicting JS etc and redoing the whole layout
- And, does it also work on both desktop + mobile? (responsive, very important!!!)

**b. improve current checkout** 
(because already responsive)

- But hen, how do I Remove step 1 for login/guest -> always guest
- and how do I Set shipping to default to - same as billing
- An how to add coupon code box to last step (so we can skip the cart)

It seems that both ways have good and bads. But I dont know what the *optimal way* to go is.

Of course we use analytics. And we see a large % exiting the funnel on multiple points. Hence this question. We see a couple of things as very imporant:

1. directly to checkout, pref no cart
2. no login/guest -> directly to address
3. All fields pref automically filled, default options ticked
4. Maybe a retrieve from FB/Twitter login button to help speed up
5. Product images & coupon code in last step (so no need for a cart view)

thanks, Sean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The best way to improve conversion is to look at your analytics and see why your customers aren't converting.**

Check the goal funnel throughout the checkout process and see if you are actually losing any customers at any stage of checkout - if you aren't then you don't need to make changes there.

This isn't a developer question - so there is no right or wrong answer. This is strictly on-site marketing and ux - and making improvements or fixes are absolutely not 1-size-fits-all.

You need to make informed decisions that suit your product range and customer demographic - based on statistical research and facts gathered from your own website (*not what you read online*).